# Authorization gate not called during service provider

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I have an `admin` gate defined in my `AuthServiceProvider` that is used to add global query scopes to some models. Suppose I had models `A`, that is observed by an `Observer` (registered in `AppServiceProvider`), and `B`, that makes use of the `admin` gate to add global query scopes.

```php
// app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
  public function boot()
  {
    Gate::define('admin', [static::class, 'admin']);
  }

  public static function admin(User $user): bool
  {
    return $user->group->name === 'Admin';
  }
}
```

```php
// app/B.php
class B extends Eloquent
{
  public static function boot()
  {
    parent::boot();

    if (!Gate::allows('admin')) {
      static::addGlobalScope('public', function ($query) {
        $query->where('public', true);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Up to this point everything worked fine. Then I added a model `C` that has an `Observer` and uses the `admin` gate. As `C::observe()` fires `C::boot()` and the `AppServiceProvider` is registered before the `AuthServiceProvider` the gate was not defined and I extracted the `Observer` registration to a new `ObserverServiceProvider` that is registered after `AuthServiceProvider`.

```php
// app/C.php
class C extends Eloquent
{
  public static function boot()
  {
    parent::boot();

    if (!Gate::allows('admin')) {
      static::addGlobalScope('public', function ($query) {
        $query->where('public', true);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

```php
// app/Providers/ObserverServiceProvider.php
class ObserverServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
  public function boot()
  {
    A::observe(AObserver::class);
    C::observe(CObserver::class);
  }
}
```

```php
// config/app.php
'providers' => [
  //...
  App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
  App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
  //...
  App\Providers\ObserverServiceProvider::class,
]
```

**My problem:**

The observers for `A` and `C` are still working, as well as the `admin` gate in `B`'s `boot()` method, but `Gate::allows('admin')` in `C` always returns `false` without even calling the gate function.

Adding a `var_dump(Gate::has('admin'))` in `C::boot()` outputs `true` and using `@can('admin')` later in the `View` during the same request works fine as well, so the gate is definitely defined and working in principle.

Comment: PS: When I move `C::observe()` from the `ObserverServiceProvider` to `C::boot()` everything is working fine, but I want all observers to be registered in the same place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authorization gate cannot be called as the session data (and therefore the authenticated user) is made available by the `StartSession` middleware, which runs after the service providers.

The problem can be solved by putting the `Gate::allows()` check inside the anonymous function, so it is only executed when building a query:

```php
// app/C.php
class C extends Eloquent
{
  public static function boot()
  {
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope('public', function ($query) {
      if (!Gate::allows('admin')) {
        $query->where('public', true);
      }
    });
  }
}
```